# How to create known quantum state in Qiskit (or any other platform) comprising of two or more bits?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, state-preparation

Is there there any way to create a known quantum state in Qiskit (or any other platform) comprising of two or more than two bit?

For example if I want to create $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}[|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|11\rangle]$. What I want to do is to know the unitary transformation ( or the quantum circuit) to prepare this (or any valid) quantum state for me.

Comment: In Qiskit, have a look at function Initialize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prepare a specific initial state of three qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/how-to-prepare-a-specific-initial-state-of-three-qubits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Vesely mentioned in the comments, you can use the `initialize` function to perform such a task. For instance, to create the state you desire, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Decompose

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
initial_state = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=float)
initial_state /= np.linalg.norm(initial_state)
qc.initialize(initial_state)
qc.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().draw("mpl")
```

which draws the following output:

[image: Decomposed circuit]

To know how does qiskit create this unitary, have a look at [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18475/10454).